# Multiple "Script src" on same page causing sorting functions not to work on HighCharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I've isolated my issue but haven't been able to fix it.  I'm hoping the brilliant minds of stack overflow can assist!

**Problem:**  The sorting function stops working when the injected tables are present.  When I remove the injections, the sorting functions work perfectly.  Is there a way for me to isolate the script src so it will work only for the injected charts?  Trying to reference them before the highcharts doesn't work.

My page:  http://www.wcsddata.net/wearewcsd

At the beginning of my page I reference the following scripts, so, my highcharts will work at the bottom of the page in the tabs:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
```

At the top, I have 4 charts that have been injected into the page via everviz and utilize "script srce":

```
<div id="highcharts-fvqBbZn4G" style="width: 100%; height: 220px; float: left; padding-bottom: 40px;"><script src="https://app.everviz.com/inject/fvqBbZn4G/" defer="defer"></script></div>
<div id="highcharts-AMGYgGD6V" style="width: 34%; height: 300px; float: left;"><script src="https://app.everviz.com/inject/AMGYgGD6V/" defer="defer"></script></div>
<div id="highcharts-pEyKRkM-l" style="width: 33%; height: 300px; float: left;"><script src="https://app.everviz.com/inject/pEyKRkM-l/" defer="defer"></script></div>
<div id="highcharts-USL8gYv5J" style="width: 33%; height: 300px; float: left;"><script src="https://app.everviz.com/inject/USL8gYv5J/" defer="defer"></script></div>
```

AT the bottom, I have tab sets that feature 8 different highcharts and many of them have the ability to sort (alphabetically, low-high and high-low).  Below is the code for one of them:

```
<script>
var categories = ['AACT', 'Allen', 'Anderson', 'Beasley', 'Beck', 'Bennett', 'Billinghurst', 'Booth', 'Brown', 'Cannan', 'Caughlin Ranch', 'Clayton', 'Cold Springs', 'Corbett', 'Damonte Ranch', 'Depoali', 'Desert Heights', 'Desert Skies', 'Diedrichsen', 'Dilworth', 'Dodson', 'Donner Springs', 'Double Diamond', 'Drake', 'Duncan', 'Dunn', 'Elmcrest', 'Galena', 'Gerlach K-12', 'Gomes', 'Gomm', 'Greenbrae', 'Hall', 'Hidden Valley', 'Huffaker', 'Hug', 'Hunsberger', 'Hunter Lake', 'Incline ES', 'Incline HS', 'Incline MS', 'Innovations', 'Inspire', 'Juniper', 'Lemelson', 'Lemmon Valley', 'Lenz', 'Lincoln Park', 'Loder', 'Mathews', 'Maxwell', 'McQueen', 'Melton', 'Mendive', 'Mitchell', 'Moss', 'Mount Rose K-8', 'Natchez', 'North Star', 'North Valleys', 'OBrien', 'Palmer', 'Peavine', 'Picollo', 'Pine', 'Pleasant Valley', 'Poulakidas', 'Reed', 'Reno', 'Risley', 'Sepulveda', 'Shaw', 'Silver Lake', 'Sky Ranch', 'Smith Alice', 'Smith Kate', 'Smithridge', 'Spanish Springs ES', 'Spanish Springs HS', 'Sparks HS', 'Sparks MS', 'Stead', 'Sun Valley', 'Swope', 'Taylor', 'TMCC HS', 'Towles', 'Traner', 'Turning Point', 'Van Gorder', 'Vaughn', 'Verdi', 'Veterans', 'Warner', 'Westergard', 'Whitehead', 'Winnemucca', 'Wooster'];
Highcharts.chart('containerfrlschl', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var points = this.series[0].points,
          chart = this,
          newPoints = [];
        Highcharts.each(points, function(point, i) {
          point.update({
            name: categories[i]
          }, false);
          newPoints.push({
            x: point.x,
            y: point.y,
            name: point.name
          });
        });
        chart.redraw();
        // Sorting A - Z
        $('#sort7').on('click', function() {
          newPoints.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a.name < b.name)
              return -1;
            if (a.name > b.name)
              return 1;
            return 0;
          });
          Highcharts.each(newPoints, function(frl, i) {
            frl.x = i;
          });
          chart.series[0].setData(newPoints, true, false, false);
        });
        // Sorting min - max
        $('#sort8').on('click', function() {
          newPoints.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.y - b.y
          });
          Highcharts.each(newPoints, function(frl, i) {
            frl.x = i;
          });
          chart.series[0].setData(newPoints, true, false, false);
        });
        // Sorting max - min
        $('#sort9').on('click', function() {
          newPoints.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b.y - a.y
          });
          Highcharts.each(newPoints, function(frl, i) {
            frl.x = i;
          });
          chart.series[0].setData(newPoints, true, false, false);
        });
      }
    }
  },
  exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
  title:{
        text:''
    },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: {
      text: 'Percentage of Student Population'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '%'
  },
credits: {
      enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
    reversed: true,
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    itemDistance: 20,
    itemStyle: {
      "font-family": "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
      "color": "#373737",
      "fontSize": "16px",
      "fontWeight": "normal"
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        filter: {
          property: 'percentage',
          operator: '>',
          value: 1
        },
        style: {
          "font-family": "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "fontSize": "14px",
          "fontWeight": "normal",
          "textOutline": false
        },
        format: '{point.y}%'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'FRL',
    color: '#00619e',
    data: [19, 100, 100, 25, 28, 100, 26, 100, 15, 100, 9, 49, 43, 100, 24, 21, 100, 100, 45, 100, 100, 59, 38, 100, 100, 55, 100, 30, 32, 41, 10, 100, 29, 53, 32, 100, 4, 47, 45, 41, 46, 45, 100, 57, 100, 100, 9, 100, 100, 100, 100, 24, 11, 40, 100, 35, 35, 100, 28, 44, 58, 100, 52, 100, 50, 19, 12, 28, 19, 100, 30, 21, 50, 23, 100, 100, 100, 13, 27, 60, 100, 100, 100, 27, 23, 18, 45, 100, 100, 13, 100, 24, 100, 100, 21, 36, 37, 52]
  }]
});</script>
```

Thank you in advance!
Ken

Comment: Surprised nobody has an answer for this yet.  Is there any additional information I can provide to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it is a general issue between integration of the **everviz** charts and the Highcharts charts. The issue occurs because **everviz** includes all Highcharts modules and doing an update on the main chart makes that this chart  "want to get access" to these modules, but assigned arguments are wrong.

Adding missing modules (**highcharts-more** and **accessibility** in this case) fixes the issue.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tqfp79c1/

```
<div id="highcharts-fvqBbZn4G" style="width: 100%; height: 220px; float: left; padding-bottom: 40px;"><script src="https://app.everviz.com/inject/fvqBbZn4G/" defer="defer"></script></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
```